# Flutter Column layout with scaled items: not readjusting

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have encountered a problem with scaled items in a `Column` layout.

(My problem is **not** with `Text` widgets. My actual code has a complex widget that's scaled  on user input. But I will demonstrate the problem with `Text` widgets instead.)

I have two `Text` items below each other in a `Column`.

The first item is scaled up inside a `Transform`.

`Column(children: [
  Transform(transform: Matrix4.identity()..scale(4.0), child:
    Text("I should not float over the thing below, despite being scaled."),
  ),
  Text("But unfortunately this happens and it pains me greately."),
]);`

The first item now floats above the second. See screenshot:

[image]

I want the layout to automatically adjust itself to new scale transformation.

Or I want the first `Text` to be cropped to a certain size (I've played around with `SizedBox` and `FittedBox` but got nowhere fast when used with a scale transformation).

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature of `Transform`. If you don't want that, don't use transform.

You could just instead do

```
new Text("foo", textScaleFactor: 4.0,)
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, my code is actually not a `Text` but a comlpex widget that is scaled. I'm using a `Text` to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: That's still the the same idea. Don't use transform. But the solution is specific to your code, which I don't have.

Comment: If I didn't use a transform, how else would I scale a widget?